# Benifit of warming up petrol engine

Tags: engine, warmup

Are there any benefits of warming up petrol engine by running it for sometime before moving or its just a myth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better for your vehicle to let it warm up before driving it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50645/is-it-better-for-your-vehicle-to-let-it-warm-up-before-driving-it) and others.

Comment: It depends. If an engine is very cold, you might need to warm it enough to allow good oil flow through the bearings, turbo lines, etc. Some old diesel engines need to be warmed up for a couple minutes before they will operate correctly. However, the time required to reach normal operating conditions in modern vehicle engines is very short - I'd say maybe ten seconds to a minute (in extreme cases.)